# When Building Signed APK :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

Tags: java, android

Having Problems with : **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class
  >   **

This is When I try to build with release signed APK. However it works when I am just Debugging or Syncing in Gradle.

I believe there is a problem with versioning the support or what ever compile dependency that is having the problem. I am just not sure what is the right path to track down the problem.

I tried Clean up then rebuild. There is no problem on Debug Build, but on Signed APK I am having this problem.

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/plivo-java-3.0.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':DailymotionWebSDK')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because both of the following libraries are including gson dependency inside them:

```
compile files('libs/plivo-java-3.0.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile project(':DailymotionWebSDK')
```

For plivo-java sdk, look at its [pom.xml](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-java/blob/master/pom.xml)

For DailyMotionWebSDK, look at its [build.gradle](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-player-sdk-android/blob/master/sdk/build.gradle)

So, you need to exlude gson from one of them.

Comment: Is there a possible way of doing that? some says if you have a .jar file it is impossible to exclude it. I tried the exclude function but it did not work.

Comment: Try including plivo-java-3.0.9.jar instead of plivo-java-3.0.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar, as in its README says `Use this if you have issues with conflicting jars in your project. See the pom.xml for the list of dependencies you will need to include.` https://github.com/plivo/plivo-java